# Converting CURL into Swift

Tags: ios, swift, curl, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble converting this into Swift, any help would be appreciated!

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts \
-u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
-d country=US \
-d managed=true
```

Comment: You should not send API requests with your secret API key directly from a mobile app, as you'd risk exposing the secret key. These requests should be sent from a backend server. (This is why Stripe does not provide Swift samples for these requests.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

    guard let URL = URL(string: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts") else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL)
    let params = "managed=true&country=us"
    request.httpBody = params.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)

    /* Start a new Task */
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            print("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you for this ! I do have one question, where would does the {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY} go? Do I just add it in the URL String? @Fahim

Comment: That part would depend on the authentication mechanism. Usually, I believe you'd be sending an encoded password rather than plain text one. If you want to figure this out on your own, you might want to give this app a try:
https://paw.cloud/

If the above helped, can you please mark the answer as "correct"?